# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate not saving

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the a mongoose model I'm trying to update right now using the `.findOneAndUpdate` method with the below code:

```
MyModel.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: "xxxxx", userId: "xxxxx" }, { $set: { completion:"xxxx", date: "xxxxx" } }, { new: true }, function(err, doc) {
  if(err) {
      return res.json({success: false, message: err.message});
  }
      res.json({success: true, message: 'success'});
});
```

When I log `doc`, it returns the updated model, but the model is not being saved to the database. Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated.

Model Code:

```
var MyModel = new Schema({
 name: {
   type: String,
   required: true
 },
 date: {
   type: Date,
   required: true
 },
 userId: {
   type: String,
   required: true
 },
 completion: {
   type: Boolean,
   required: true
 }
});
```

Comment: please provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What more do you need @NguyễnThanhTú, I've provided the non-working source code. Thanks

Comment: The code looks okay. Did you check the collection you are updating and collection you are checking are the same. @Viper

Comment: Yes, they are the same. I'm really at a loss as to why this is happening @ViKiG

Comment: Add the `Schema` to above code. Also, the `"xxxxx"` in your code, are those variables and if they are, where are you writing the values for them. So, you should add the code running around above code.

Comment: I added the model @ViKiG

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues as per your posted code:

1) `MyModel` is a `Schema` object, you will have to create a `Model` object like this -

```
    var model = mongoose.Model('modelName', MyModel); // where MyModel is a Schema object
```

Then using the above `model` object you can run your `findOneAndUpdate`, like in your code (like `model.findOneAndUpdate`).

2) Secondly, in the `MyModel` Schema you have not given the collection name. You can put it in the options object which comes after the schema object argument. So you should put:

```
    var MyModel = new Schema({schema object...}, {collection: 'mongodbCollectionName'});
```

If you do not give above option,mongoose would create a default collection using the `model` name.

I believe if (1) is not there, (2) is most likely causing the issue in your case.